# Repainting a single component among many

Tags: java, swing, awt, repaint, java-2d

I have a question about repainting a graphic object in Java.

I have a `JPanel` on which I draw polygons or rectangles.  When I double-click in a polygon, the polygon is identified and it is rendered by a certain color. However the way I'm doing this seems very ineffective because I repaint the entire panel while only one of them needs to be repainted. Now my question is:

Can we define and call a paint method for a `Rectangle` or `GeneralPath` (used as polygon)? If yes, would you please recommend a link to explain that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`repaint(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

> Adds the specified region to the dirty region list if the component is showing. The component will be repainted after all of the currently pending events have been dispatched.